# Css and Javascripts not loading on login page in Django?

Tags: django

Here is my settings file.. I am getting the login page but the css and javascripts are not loading.
I gotthe whole project and i have to start working on it but i only know the basic of django so not sure why css and javascripts arenot loading. this is a very old project so it is using python 2.6.5 and django 1.3. the folder structure is also old.

```
# Django settings for athena.
import socket


# determine whether it's prod or dev or test/uat
if socket.gethostname().split('.')[0].lower().strip() in ('athena-dev', 'athena-test',     'lucid32'):
ATHENA_PROD_MODE = False
elif socket.gethostname().split('.')[0].lower().strip() == 'athena':
ATHENA_PROD_MODE = True
else:
raise Exception('cannot determine what mode (prod or dev) to operate in')
ATHENA_UAT_MODE = (socket.gethostname().split('.')[0].lower().strip() == 'athena-test')


if ATHENA_PROD_MODE:
DEBUG = False
else:
DEBUG = True


TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG


ADMINS = (('PASystemSupport', 'pasystemsupport@apa.org'), )
MANAGERS = ADMINS


if ATHENA_PROD_MODE:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Athena',
        'USER': 'ftdbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'f0lt5xt',
        'HOST': 'PIDB-SQL',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server',
            'autocommit': True,
            'dsn': 'PIDB-SQL',
            'use_mars': True
        }
    }
}
elif ATHENA_UAT_MODE:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Athena-UAT',
        'USER': 'ftdbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'f0lt5xt',
        'HOST': 'LANDB-DEV',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server',
            'autocommit': True,
            'dsn': 'LANDB-DEV',
            'use_mars': True
        }
    }
}
else:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/vagrant/Athena/athena_root/athena.db',
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/vagrant/Athena/athena_root/athena_static/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/athena_static/'

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '7*f!l)^v!81vog@yzd23scp5+30db=)bub(j88nz!37nnt62mh'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'athena_root.athena.middleware.ApplyAuthentication',
'athena_root.athena.workflow.middleware.ProdViewPermissions'
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'athena_root.athena.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('/vagrant/Athena/athena_root/athena_templates',
             '/vagrant/Athena/athena_root/ltt/templates',
             '/vagrant/Athena/athena_root/errata/templates')

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"athena_root.athena.template_context_proc.baseTemplateContext"
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.humanize',
'athena_root.athena',
'athena_root.ltt',
'athena_root.errata'
)

EMAIL_HOST = 'mailhost.apa.org'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'PASystemsupport@apa.org'

LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'null': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        'include_html': True
    },
    'aem_db_logger': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'athena_root.errata.log.DatabaseLoggingHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'athena_root.errata': {
        'handlers': ['aem_db_logger'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True
    }
}
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('athena_root.athena.auth.backends.AthenaAuthBackend',)
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout'

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 7257600
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
```

`

Comment: try opening the css/js file in new tab .. try serving your static media with your main urls.py .. you dont have staticfile_dirs defined .. etc..check thouroughly.. then come on stackoverflow.. otherwise all you will get is negative votes .. take a look at this page and check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/

Comment: i tried doing that but its just not working